# Deploy jar files to Archiva manually

Tags: maven, ivy, archiva

I have a lot of jar files in my local hard drive and I want to use them as a repository so that my internet connection requirement can be removed.

I installed Archiva but I don't know how can I deploy the jar files to Archiva. there is a UI form which does this task but deploying huge amount of jar files by hand is not easy and waste a lot of time.

How can I use my local jar files as a repository so that I can use Maven(or Ivy) to manage dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload them with [`mvn deploy:deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html), which you could use in a script for a bulk upload ([discussed here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200903.mbox/%3C8468db6a0903281005p128acf36v52a9c82dd043b237@mail.gmail.com%3E), and [here's an example script](http://devgrok.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/bulk-upload-of-maven-artifacts-to.html)).

As an alternative, if you want to use those local files directly, you can copy them into the storage location of an Archiva repository. From [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.archiva.user/1782):

> One way to put all your local .m2 repository content is to copy from
>   ~/.m2/repository to
>   ${archiva-install-dir}/data/repository/${managed-repository-name}/
>
> ...
>
> Once the copy is done, you can force Archiva d/b scan on the managed
>   repository.